# Handle errors on mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

When I have one error from the server, I pass one function called "formatErrors".

```
try {
  // everything okay with mongoose!
} catch (err) {
  // Error!
  return {
    ok: false,
    errors: formatErrors(err, models)
  }
}
```

the function formatErrors looks like this:

```
import pick from 'lodash.pick';

export default (err, models) => {
  if (err instanceof models.mongoose.Error.ValidationError) {
    return [{ path: 'mongoose', message: err }]
  }
  return [{ path: 'name', message: 'something went wrong' }];
};
```

So, my intention is to handle the mongoose error, and return it like this:

```
{
  path: 'mongoose',
  message: 'MONGOOSE ERROR BLA BLA BLA'
}
```

But the function to handle that, doesn't work. What can I do?

Thank you!

Comment: You can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50905750/error-handling-in-async-await/50906614#50906614

Comment: yeah! it works :)